# LibGdx new screen reacts to touch from old screen

Tags: java, button, libgdx, listener

I am making a LibGdx game. I have a main menu with a button that sends the user to the play screen. When at play screen though, the game reacts as it would when the user clicks in the spot that the button is located in from the previous screen. Here is the code that defines the button and switches screens:

```
button = new TextButton("Play", button_text);
button.setWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4);
button.setHeight(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 8);
button.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) - (button.getWidth() / 2), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) - (button.getHeight() / 2));
stage.addActor(button);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
button.addListener(new InputListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
        game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));
        dispose();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Here is the dispose method for this screen:

```
    @Override
public void dispose() {
    stage.dispose();
}
```

So how do I clear all input before moving from one screen to the next?

Comment: Can you post PlayScreen class and its listener methods? Probably an issue with misunderstanding the touch events. (For a quick fix to the problem I think you have, can you change the touchDown method to touchUp above?)

Comment: I found the solution to my problem and posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research I have discovered a solution to my problem.

To solve this problem, in the constructor of the new screen I set the input proccessor to a new instance of an implementation of the GestureListener interface.

```
private MyGestureListener myGestureListener;

public PlayScreen(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
    myGestureListener = new MyGestureListener();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(myGestureListener));
}
```

Giving each screen its own instance of a GestureListener will avoid the problem of input being carried on from one screen to the next.

Answer (score 2):

Add on the dispose method

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
```

and will be fixed

Comment: Please don't just post "try this" style answers.  Instead, try to explain why you're making your recommendation.

Comment: I responded using the phone sorry. That thing is the usual thing to do when switching screens. You can always put that on the hide(); or setting the input on the new screen.